# spring security: send redirect in case of exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have a question about Spring Security.

My idea is that in the case when the SM_USER header is wrong I don't want to send an uncatched exception (as the method `loadUserByUsername` of my class `CustomUserDetailsService` does).

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {...}
```

I want to catch it and thus redirect to the default page (with mapping `my/default/page`) and write a message text there like: *try again please*.

I already have an ExceptionResolver but it works only on controller level and not earlier.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionResolver {

    @ExceptionHandler(PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException.class)       
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleBindException(PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        ...
        return response;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotFoundException.class)      
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleBindException(UsernameNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        ...
        return response;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand I need to implement a new exception resolver for such cases, but when I try to built it in the application context, my whole programm crashes down.

```
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public class GlobalExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver{

@Override
protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse responce, Object handler, Exception exception) {

    try {
        responce.sendRedirect("/my/defualt/page");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
     if(exception instanceof PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException){
        mav.addObject("errorMessage","This user does not exist");
     }
     else  if(exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException){
         mav.addObject("errorMessage","This user is too old");
     }
     return mav;
    }
}
```

So, please, could you explain me how can I realize my plan in this case if spring security allows this in general?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "works only on controller level and not earlier." What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Ankit, pre-authentification of SM_USER header happens before the methods of controller classes start, so the class `ExceptionResolver` described in above does not catcht exceptions thrown in `loadUserByUsername()` method of `CustomUserDetailsService` class

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring xml you can call one bean with @PostConstruct when failed like this

```
<sec:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="afterLoginFail"
```

Example AfterLoginFail

```
public class AfterLoginFail extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?status=failure");
    }

}
```

Or if you use javaconfig use `formLogin().failureUrl(authenticationFailureUrl)` or `.failureHandler()`

Comment: thank you! do I need to register `AfterLoginFail` with `@Bean` annotation? How do I add this ti spring security?